# Moving data from MS Access to SharePoint

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint

I've been trying to move my MSAccess database to SharePoint. However the move data to SharePoint button in Ms Access 2010 is disabled.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Your database is not in a Trusted Location, You don't have Admin privileges on your machine or You don't have a 'Full' version of MS Access.  One of those three usually hinder tasks.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the database that you are trying to move is not in the newer Access file format (.accdb or .accde).  The older .mdb file format does not support the feature of moving data to SharePoint.

If the database is not in the correct Access file format, you can easily convert it.  Open your database in MS Access, then save it using the Save As menu option to save it as a .accdb file.